# Probability of collect a subset, where its componets are largest, in the set of number?

Tags: probability

I get in a trouble in probability and I would like to have your help. My problem is that:

Given an array that includes  $N$ real numbers as $A=[a_1 a_2 a_3 \cdots a_N]$.
Now, take a sub-array  as $B=[a_1 a_2 a_3]$

What is probability that all components of $B$ are largest value among  $N$ component in $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $N$ different numbers there is exactly one triple consisting of the three largest numbers. Given that you choose a triple at random the probability that you choose this "maximal" triple is $1\bigl/{N\choose3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!